# How to make a sitefinity master page without ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity, master-pages

The company I am working for has a sitefinity. They want me to create custom pages from scratch for them. I have never used sitefinity, so upon research It appears that I want to create a template via .master. Then once built, I would add to my CMS and access it for use.

Is there a way to make these .master templates other than ASP.NET? ( which I have no experience with)

Essentially all am am wanting to do is create a custom page out of html,css, and jquery and then make a 'template' out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use a .master page to create a template in Sitefinity. It's nice to have that level of control but it's not necessary at all. Just go to Design > Page Templates in the Sitefinity backend section /Sitefinity

There are several built in templates you can edit from that page. You can use one of those templates, create a new template from scratch, or create a template based on any one of the templates you see there.

Once you pick a template, you can edit the Layout to add columns and global content or custom CSS. 
[image: This is what the page templates section looks like]

Answer (score 1):

Not really, if you want control over the markup then you'll have to use a .master page but the good news is that it really is just mostly html and css / js references. Sitefinity has a [sample template here](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/designer-s-guide/page-templates/creating-a-template-using-master-pages) but you may want to look at their Visual Studio plugin called [Thunder](http://www.sitefinity.com/resources/tools/sitefinity-thunder) to register a template. It will add in a default master page as well as the default folder structure for the theme, [video on that here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDiYUbNlWCc).